# Finding a suitable Liapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes

For any $\alpha<0$, the critical point $(0,0)$ of the system $$\begin{cases}
x'=\alpha x+y+x^2y\\
y'=-x+ay\cos(x)
\end{cases}$$
is strictly stable.

Then I try two types of Liapunov function such as $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$, where $b^2-4ac<0$ and for another one is $x^{2m}+y^{2n}$. I found that the significant problem is tackling the positivity of $x^2y$.

Do you have any ideas

Comment: It is not important what the sign of that term is, but that it is not too large close to the origin.

Comment: Umm, you are right.  But because after multiplying the partial derivative of the Lyapunov function, it will give us an odd power. So we can't determine the sign and find any term that cancels it out, so I can't claim that the partial derivative of the Lyapunov function with respect to time is strictly less than zero.

Answer (score 1):

For the radius length you get
$$
rr'=xx'+yy'=αr^2+r^4\cos^3\theta\sin\theta+αr\sin\theta(\cos(r\cos(\theta)-1)
$$
Using $|\sin\theta|\le 1$ etc. and $0\le 1-\cos\phi=2\sin^2(\phi/2)\le \frac12\phi^2$, this gives an estimate of
$$
rr'\le -|α|r^2+(1+|α|/2)r^4.
$$
The right side is negative as long as $r^2\le\frac{|α|}{1+|α|/2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to show the stictly stable by radius length of this concept.

Comment: The Lyapunov function is the standard example $V=\frac12r^2=\frac12(x^2+y^2)$. Inside the identified circle you get $\dot V < 0$, which proves asymptotic stability.